# A linear operator is continuous if and only if it maps cauchy sequences to cauchy sequences

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, cauchy-sequences

Let $A$ and $B$ be seminormed spaces, then I want to show that a linear operator $T: A \rightarrow B$ is continuous if and only if it maps cauchy sequences to cauchy sequences.

The direction "$T$ continuous $\Rightarrow$ $T$ maps cauchy sequences to cauchy sequences" is easy, because any linear continuous operator is a bounded operator.

But I'm stuck on the other direction, I'm aware that I can equivalently show that $T$ is continuous in $0$ or that $T$ is a bounded operator.

Any advice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose $T$ is not bounded. So, there is a sequence of elements $(x_n)$ of A with norm $1$ such that $\|T(x_n)\| > n^2$. But then the sequence $y_n = \frac{1}{n} x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, because $\|y_n - y_{n+k}\| < \left |\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n+k} \right| < \frac{2}{n}$ and $\|T(y_n)\| = \frac{1}{n} \|T(x_n)\| > n$ that is not Cauchy (because it's not bounded).

Comment: The question is about seminormed spaces. Not that that makes _much_ of a difference.

Comment: @DanielFischer you mean we can't say that $y_n$ is convergent? That may jeopardize my remark about it's being convergent but not about being Cauchy, right?

Comment: Whether $y_n$ must converge depends. The thing is that the topology on both spaces is induced by a family of seminorms, and you need to consider pairs of seminorms. For every continuous seminorm $q$ on $B$, you need to find a continuous seminorm $p$ on $A$ such that there is a $C$ with $q(Tx) \leqslant C\cdot p(x)$ for all $x\in A$. A sequence being Cauchy means that $\lim_{m,n\to\infty} p(x_n - x_m) = 0$ for all continuous seminorms $p$.

Comment: Ah, yes that works, thank you. I'm not sure what Daniel wants to imply but $y_n$ is convergent (at least in an $\epsilon - \delta$ way), even in just a seminormed space.

Comment: @DanielFischer why a family of seminorms?

Comment: @user49797 Are your topologies induced by a single seminorm? [Or finitely many.] Then it's basically the same as for normed spaces. If the topologies are induced by infinite families of seminorms, it's a little more to do.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Because I'm used to "seminormed spaces" being a synonym of "locally convex spaces".

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, they are induced like in the case of a normed space.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks a lot for your remark, I was thinking about only one seminorm and the thought never occurred to me that we could define a Cauchy Sequence the way you said, because I'm used to forget topology when talking about completeness properties (such as Cauchy Sequences). I'll think a bit more.